# Python - Is it possible to get the init params of a Python class?

Tags: python

So for example let's say I initialize a class like so

```
blah = SomeClass(a=10,b=20)
```

is it possible to get a dictionary of the initialization parameters and their values from `blah`? So like

```
get_init_params_and_values(blah)
```

should return {'a':10, 'b':20}. `SomeClass` can have other `__init__` parameters but I only care about `a` and `b` since they were set when initialized.

I'm not super familiar with this specific functionality but I remember you can get the parameters of a function. So if that's possible for `__init__` then let's say we get a list of param names then maybe can get it from the class like so `blah.some_param_name`.

Comment: Not unless the class stores the initialization parameters somewhere. Do you control `SomeClass`? If so, it would be fairly easy to store those and get them later yourself.

Comment: Would it be possible to get all initialization parameters from the `__init__` function then do something like `blah.param_name`?

Comment: If this were possible, it would require all class instances to keep a reference to those arguments, even in the extremely common cases where the instance doesn't need to remember the arguments and it's just a waste of memory. For example, `list(whatever)` really shouldn't keep a reference to `whatever`.

Comment: blah.__dict__ should give you all the class attributes and their values in a dictionary format.

Comment: "Is it possible to find out what the cow looked like by looking at the hamburger?"

Comment: You can get function parameter names but not the values from an executing function instance. Similarly, you could get the names of the `__init__` parameters, but the actual values from any given class instantiation are lost when `__init__` exits. `__init__` may have saved them, but that's unique to each class.

Comment: So, the answer is no, you cannot get the initialization values in any standard way. And you wouldn't want to. Why would a class instance be forced to keep references to its init parameters unless it wanted to?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the names of the parameters from the `__init__` function object itself, and you can get the names of the attributes from the `__dict__` attribute of `blah`:

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self._a = a
...         self._b = b
...
>>> SomeClass.__init__.__code__.co_varnames
('self', 'a', 'b')
>>> blah = SomeClass(a=10,b=20)
>>> blah.__dict__
{'_a': 10, '_b': 20}
```

but note that they are not necessarily the same, even in number.  There is no way to reliably determine which attributes in `blah.__dict__` go with which parameters in `SomeClass.__init__`, if they even go together at all:

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self._c = a + b
...
>>> blah = SomeClass(a=10,b=20)
>>> blah.__dict__
{'_c': 30}
```

In this second example there is no way to tell from `blah` what values were passed for `a` and `b`, because these values go out of scope as soon as `__init__` returns and they are not stored anywhere (only their sum is stored, as `_c`).